# Ruby Nokogiri getting plain text file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to get a .sql file from an http web server using this code.

```ruby
Nokogiri::HTML(open($sql_file,:http_basic_authentication=>[@usr, @pwd]))
```

But i do get the sql file with some html tags.(e.g `<html><body><p>` at the beginning and at the end).

**Do you know how can i get the file as plain text .sql file.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri is for handling HTML and XML files. If you just want the raw text file, you don't need or want Nokogiri.

Use just the  `open-uri` library (which you are already using) along with its [`read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-read) method to fetch the contents:

```
require 'open-uri'
sql = open($sql_file,:http_basic_authentication=>[@usr, @pwd]).read
```

Comment: I figure this out :). But Thank you anyways.